# How to add one common XML attribute to multiple elements

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling, xml-attribute

I have an object that I get back from a REST API in XML format. I can create and update this object type. In my Rest client, I want to supply an attribute with some of my elements. Let's say I can specify an attribute like access="LOCKED" to make that field read-only in the user interface.

**Example: User Object**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class User {

private String userName;
private String userId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;

@XmlAttribute(name="username")
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

@XmlAttribute(name = "userId", namespace = "some namespace")
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

@XmlElement(name = "FirstName")
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@XmlElement(name = "LastName")
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Email")
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

**Marshaling with JAXB:**

```
User user = User.builder().email("e@mail.com").userName("jd")
      .userId("123").firstName("Jane").lastName("Doe").build();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Iser.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(user, System.out);
```

Assuming that I want to set the access for Email and LastName, How would you annotate this "access" attribute to put it on each of these Elements?

**Expected output with the access attribute:**

```
<User username="jd" ns:userId="123">
    <FisrtName>Jane</FirstName>
    <LastName access="LOCKED">Doe</LastName>
    <Email access="LOCKED">e@mail.com</Email>
</User>
```

Comment: one solution is to make the elements objects on their own and then they can have attributes of their own. This comes with a lot of duplicate code though.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Example: User Object**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;


@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class User {

private String userName;
private String userId;
private String firstName;
private LastName lastName;
private Email email;


@XmlAttribute(name="username")
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

@XmlAttribute(name = "userId", namespace = "some namespace")
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

@XmlElement(name = "FirstName")
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

       @XmlRootElement(name = "LastName")
       @XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class LastName{
    @XmlValue
     public String lastnme;
    //put getters and setters
    @XmlAttribute(name ="access")
    public String access;
    //put getters and setters

    }


    @XmlRootElement(name = "Email")
       @XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Email{
    @XmlValue
     public String Email_id;
    //put getters and setters
    @XmlAttribute(name ="access")
    public String access;
    //put getters and setters

    }

}
```

**Marshaling with JAXB:**

```
User.Lastname lastname = new User.Lastname();
lastname.setlastnme("Doe");
lastname.setAccess("LOCKED");

user.Email email_id = new user.Email();
email_id.setEmail_Id("e@mail.com");
email_id.setAccess("LOCKED");

User user = User.builder().email(email_id).userName("jd")
      .userId("123").firstName("Jane").lastName(lastname).build();

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Iser.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(user, System.out);
```

Comment: changed the code with new one.Pls try. Suggest better one if you have come accross pls.